Ubuntu SFTP Server Permissions
I'm trying to create a SFTP server using Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS, and I'm having trouble copying to the folder I created:

The sshd_config sets ChRootDirectory to \sftpsrv, which is a mounted disk specifically for SFTP files
I am not able to create a folder inside \sftpsrv or assign permissions to a user and send files to that folder; my goal is to have something like:
\sftpsrv\linux
\sftpsrv\windows
\sftpsrv\firewall


I want only one user, so to copy files to these folders I could use something like this, but after trying the first part, as soon as I try to copy the file, I get permission denied:
copy sftp://{user}:{password}@{IP}/linux/{filename}




Can anyone help me solve this?
Root is the owner of /sftpsrv and sftpuser is the owner of the others folders.

What are the permissions and ownership on the /sftpsrv directory (and any subdirectories like /sftpsrv/linux)? Try running "ls -laR" in the /sftpsrv directory, then [edit] your question to include the output.

I edited it now!

what do you get from sudo namei -l /sftpsrv  ?

I get:drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root sftpsrv

The answer was create a new user, change permission of subfolders to that user and the specific group and it's working now!
